# Bishul Akum Technology

Tags: halacha, appliances, bishul-akum

Is there Bishul Akum when using a microwave, considering that it is not cooking as it was in the times of Chazal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's debated by contemporary poskim (and can come up in many dairy restaurants that use a microwave to make eggs).  From what I've heard (a friend of mine spoke to the OU's Rabbi Genack, who asked RSZ"A, if I recall correctly), R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach held it was a problem (though he does not consider the microwave to be cooking vis-a-vis shabbos).  My impression is that many American poskim are lenient.

[Here's Rabbi Jachter stating similarly](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/12-16%20Bishul%20Akum.htm).

Answer (score 0):

in ialcut iosef shabat he brings that microwave is safek if it considered bishul. In practive we should be stringent.
in regards shabat it means that something prepared using a microwave could not be reheated in a plata because it is safek that it is already cooked.
while I personally understood the halacha that we posek lehumra maybe you could assume that it is safek miderabanan lecula. but this is rather bediavad and not lechatehila.