# Microwave oven and goy (me) cooking

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, appliances, bishul-akum

Is cooking kosher food by a Goy - in this case me (doing giyur) in a microwave oven making the *oven* unsuitable for use by a Jew?

I asked one rabbi who said there is no halakhic issue. I live in a house of a very frum person (a hasidic rabbi, very much into kaballah, baruch hashem) and he always wants to turn the oven for me, so he has a part in the cooking. Does it come from kaballah - is goyish cooking able to damage the utensil?

Of course there is no milchig-fleichig mixing (everything is parve), it is not cooking for a Jew (bishul akum should not be a problem if only the goy eats what he prepared *and* food is cooked in a sealed vessel), furthermore everything has to be pre-packaged and brought to the kitchen unopened, has to have a reliable hechsher and the rabbi trusts the food I brought is kosher. Food is *always* cooked in sealed containers made of plastic. In my opinion there must be some kaballistic teaching about food prepared by a goy, being not forbidden (in this case), but undesirable for a Jew. Is there a halakha on this? What is the reason for this stricture?

Comment: Hmm.  There is a rule about a Jew lighting the oven, but I've no idea if that applies to microwaves!

Comment: that's because of bishul akum. here the food is _not going to be eaten by a Jew_

Comment: Oh right; you did say that you were asking about the *microwave*, not the *food*.  (For some reason I assumed he might also be eating the food, but you didn't say that.)

Comment: well, bishul akum would apply to both if a microwave is a vessel. here there is no non-kosher food, food has special containers, and one rabbinic authority (I mean an Orthodox Rav) here in Toronto says it is ok to use it by a Jew afterwards. I'm asking what possible motivation the 2nd rabbi has (and if there is a remedy). The 2nd rabbi is very strict, maybe it is his custom or chumra, maybe it has grounds in halakha or kaballah - I would like to know, if it is the latter, what remedy I could propose - like if I was his employee maybe there would be no problem, I'm not sure.

Comment: to some extent the situation is similar to a traditional oven used by a non-Jew to cook some eggs - is there any way this can make the oven unsuitable for a Jew?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the combination of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4210 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14569

Comment: Can someone show me how is this a duplicate if none of the questions from the combination _a)_ mention food cooked in a sealed container _b)_ ask about not just halakhic (the rav obviously knew one can even cook in a hotel microwave oven in sealed container, as the other rabbi pointed out) __BUT__ possibly kaballistic explanation - is food cooked by a non-Jew 'impure'? _ONE_ reason Bishul Akum is forbidden is because it comes from 'Akum', an assumed idolater, and meal offerings existed among 'Akum', so on some level the oven is used for idolatry. I wont do idolatry, but a rule may exist still.

Comment: Re your last comment, note that the question didn't mention sealed containers until after it was marked as a duplicate. The only difference between this question and the combination of http://yodeya.com/q/4210 and http://yodeya.com/q/14569 is now some particulars very particular to your case, which doesn't make me, for one, want to reopen the question: see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734. If you're asking about whether halachically permissible food cooked by a non-Jew (or even impermissible such food) is (also) a problem in the eyes of cabala, I propose that you just ask that.

Comment: You are right, I should have asked just about cabala. Well, I have learned which question to ask, that's a success for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a non-Jew cooks food of the type which is not normally eaten raw, then the food is forbidden for a Jew, and the utensils may not be used by a Jew until they are koshered.

Many Ashkenazi (European) Jews are lenient that if a Jew lit the fire, then this law does not apply. Sephardic Jews (Spanish, North African or Oriental origin) are more strict, and for them, just turning on the stove would not be sufficient.

This law applies to food which is not normally eaten raw, and is the type which would be eaten by a king, so it doesn't apply to very cheap types of foods such as sardines or baked beans.

Comment: again - bishul akum does not apply. food has special containers and it is written on them 'not kosher for a Jew'. The food is _always_ cooked in these special containers, so there is no contact with the oven. 

The problem is - is the oven itself a vessel or not? Is 1 layer of separation enough? 

If it is not, there is no halakha against using it by a Jew afterwards, this is the ruling of 1st Local Orthodox Authority. The 2nd LOA in whos house I live still wants to start the oven for some reason. It is either a chumra of the 2nd rabbi or it comes from kaballah and he does not like questioning

Comment: there is a machlokes if coffee or tea potentially qualify as bishul akum, since they may be served on a great banquet. thank you for the answer emeslyaakov.